# NRA who has unearned income on Form 1042-S

Tags: united-states, irs, non-resident, dtaa, form-w-8-ben

I need to recover taxes reported on a Form 1042-S for my grandchildren who are non native, Native Americans. Under the [Dual Tax Avoidance Agreement / treaty between Germany/USA](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/germany.pdf), I submitted a W8-BEN to the Reservation and bank who maintains the minors account.

The reservation asked their tax accountants and said I need to recover on Form 8233 but after reading the form they state <**Claiming only foreign status or treaty benefits with respect to income that is NOT compensation for personal services**> to use Form W8-BEN.

Do I submit a 1040NR, 8833, W8-BEN to the IRS?  Any advise is appreciated, thanks, GRV